# Django 2.0 Form is not saving data to database

Tags: python, django, forms

so I have a very simple blog app and I'm trying to figure out why the data entered in the form doesn't save to the database and it doesn't redirect me to my index page.

forms.py

```
from django import forms

class NewBlog(forms.Form):
  blogger = forms.CharField(max_length=20, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs=  
  {'placeholder' : 'Name'}))
  text = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={'placeholder' : 
  'Text'}))
```

new_blog.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>New Blog</title>
</head>
<body>
   <form action="{% url 'new_blog' %}" method="POST">
   {% csrf_token %}
   <h2>Write your blog here:</h2>
   {{ form }}
   <br>
   <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from .models import BlogPost
from .forms import NewBlog

def index(request):
  blogs = BlogPost.objects.all()
  context = {'blogs' : blogs}
  return render(request, 'blog/index.html', context)

def newBlog(request):
   if request == 'POST':
     form = NewBlog(request.POST)
   if form.is_valid():
     blogger = form.cleaned_data['blogger'] 
     text = form.cleaned_data['text'] 
     new_blog = BlogPost(blogger = blogger, text = text)
     new_blog.save()
     return redirect('index')
   else:
     form = NewBlog()
  context = {'form' : form}
  return render(request, 'blog/new_blog.html', context)
```

Comment: Do you get a stacktrace or just nothing happens? Also, might see the problem already. If your form is not valid, you should be returning something that indicates it. Right now, it just creates a new form in this case. I think you are missing an `else` for your `is_valid` call.

Comment: @MrName Once I hit submit, the page just reloads with a blank form

Comment: Can we see your URLs patterns?

Comment: @Lemayzeur ``from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
  path('', views.index, name='index'),
  path('new_blog/', views.newBlog, name='new_blog')``

Comment: Your second `if form.is_valid():` is not correctly indented. Please pay attention to indentation when posting python code as python is whitespace sensitive. We can not know if this a typo from copy and pasting or an actual coding error.

Comment: Have you tried form.save()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is likely to be the first line of your view.

```
if request == 'POST':
```

should be:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
```

Answer (score 0):

To save an Object into database
instead of

```
new_blog = BlogPost(blogger = blogger, text = text)
new_blog.save()
```

use the best way:

```
BlogPost.objects.create(blogger = blogger, text = text)
```

It will be automatically saved